# What is complexity of my code and how can I improve it?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, search

This is the problem from the CSES problem set.

There are n applicants and m free apartments. Your task is to distribute the apartments so that as many applicants as possible will get an apartment.

Each applicant has a desired apartment size, and they will accept any apartment whose size is close enough to the desired size.

> **Input**
>
> The first input line has three integers n, m, and k: the number of
>   applicants, the number of apartments, and the maximum allowed
>   difference.
>
> The next line contains n integers a1,a2,…,an: the desired apartment
>   size of each applicant. If the desired size of an applicant is x, he
>   or she will accept any apartment whose size is between x−k and x+k.
>        The last line contains m integers b1,b2,…,bm: the size of each apartment.
>
> **Output**
>
> ```
>  Print one integer: the number of applicants who will get an apartment.
> ```
>
> **Constraints**
>
> ```
> 1 ≤ n, m ≤ 2e5
> 0 ≤ k ≤ 1e9
> 1 ≤ ai, bi ≤ 1e9
> ```

My attempt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
typedef long long int ll;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);
    int n, m, k;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;
    vector<int> vn, vm;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int p;
        cin >> p;
        vn.push_back(p);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        int p;
        cin >> p;
        vm.push_back(p);
    }
    int c = 0;
    sort(vn.begin(), vn.end());
    sort(vm.begin(), vm.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < vn.size(); j++)
        {
            if (vm[i] <= vn[j] + k && vm[i] >= vn[j] - k)
            {
                c++;
                vn.erase(vn.begin() + j);
                break;
            }
            if (vn[j] < vm[i] - k)
            {
                vn.erase(vn.begin() + j);
                j--;
                continue;
            }
            if (vn[j] > vm[i] + k)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << c << "\n";
}
```

I got a time limit exceeded in some of the test cases.

Comment: You should really figure out the time complexity of your solution before you implement it so that you don't waste time implementing stuff that will never be fast enough. On first glance your code seems to be at least `O(n^2)` or `O(nm)` which is definitely not fast enough for `n, m <= 2e5`.

Comment: i wonder if you can put two occupants of size 5 into a single apartment of size 10 ?

Comment: if you have a strict "one apartment -- one occupant" rule, just put your occupants and apartments into a single array, sort (O(NlogN) and make a single pass (O(N)) to find out apartment-occupant pairs using simple `if-then-else` logic.

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm in words, relegating the code to a backup explanation? Based on that description, what would you expect the complexity to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution just got accepted

Ideas:

- For each applicant, calculate their respective range based on `k`.
- Remove the applicants who will never get assigned to any one of the given apartments
- Sort the applicants' ranges
- Sort the apartments
- Now for each apartment, find the first applicant whose range includes the size of the apartment
- Once an applicant is found, assign him/her to the current apartment and remove him/her from a candidate for next apartments

Python Solution

```
def solve(applicants, apartments, k):
    apartments.sort()
    dapps = sorted([(applicant-k, applicant+k)
                    for applicant in applicants if applicant - k <= apartments[-1]], reverse=True)
    cnt = 0

    for dep in apartments:
        while dapps and dapps[-1][1] < dep:
            dapps.pop()
        if dapps and dapps[-1][0] <= dep <= dapps[-1][1]:
            cnt += 1
            dapps.pop()
    return cnt
```

- Time complexity: O(NlogN + MlogM)
- Space complexity: O(N)

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of your algorithm is O(m*n^2), though practically we can say it is O(n^3).

For your reference, it is O(n^3) because you have two for loops, creating a complexity of O(n^2), however in those loops there is a function call to std::vector.erase(), the erase function is a linear operation, O(n) so we multiply it to O(n^2) and get a time complexity of O(n^3). If you need more clarity on this please reach out to me.

Now onto your question of what is the ideal runtime. This is a sorting/searching problem clearly. I believe this can be done in O(n^2).

My Solution:

Sort the apartment sizes and each applicant desired in ascending order. 
Fill the apartments in order, starting with the pickiest "tenants", the ones with the lowest desired size. Note this is "O(n^2)" but is practically much faster than a standard O(n^2) algorithm.

Pseudo-code:

```
        int count = 0;
        vector<int> desired, apartments;
        //Fill these vectors
        //Sort the vectors
        for(int apt = 0; apt < apartments.size();apt++){
            for(int person = 0;person < desired.size();person++){
               if(canEnterApartment(desired.at(person),apartments.at(apt)){
                 count++;
                 //Remove all tenants before this
                 break;
               }
            }
         }
         return count;
```

Comment: The complexity of the OP's code is actually less than that. You assumed the `erase` is always linear, but you forgot to take into account that it decreases the size of the vector. This means it can only be called `O(n)` times in total, so the complexity from the erase operations is `O(n^2)`. The complexity of the rest of the code is `O(nm)`, so overall it's `O(n(n + m))` or `O(n^2 + nm)`. It's still not good enough in this case but sometimes differences like this matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find + Priority Queue, to solve this problem.
Have a Max Priority Queue with all bx as values.
Do a find (refer [Priority Queue with a find function - Fastest Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974292/priority-queue-with-a-find-function-fastest-implementation)) in priority queue with ax.
In Priority Queue comparator function instead of checking for ax == bx, check (bx >= ax - k) && (bx <= ax + k). if found, an apartment can be allocated to him.